# how to iterate through select element in each row for conditional checking

Tags: jquery

My page has many rows and each row has a select element as shown.

```
<tr><td>row1</td><td><select name='action_select1'></td></tr>
<tr><td>row1</td><td><select name='action_select1'></td></tr>
<tr><td>row1</td><td><select name='action_select1'></td></tr>
<tr><td>row1</td><td><select name='action_select1'></td></tr>
```

....

Now I have to conditionally append option values for each select item but when i am iterating it, throws error cannot append element on object.

```
 var algSelect=grid.find('select[name=action_col1]');
    var array_sort = [{ name:'None', value:'none'},{name:'Source', value:'source'},{name:'Calculations', value:'calc'}];
    var temp_obj=[];
    for(var k; k<=algSelect.length;k++){
        temp_obj=algSelect[k];
        _.each(array_sort, function(gen) {
           if(some_cond_here)
            temp_obj.append('<option value="' + gen.value +'" title="'+gen.name+'">' + gen.name + '</option>');
        });
    }
```

How do i conditionally add options for each select Item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('select[name="action_col1"]')` will return a jQuery object - which has all of jQuery's methods : `.append()`, `.css()`, `.val()` ...

`algSelect[k]`, on the other hand, will return a bare DOM node. If you want to manipulate it using jQuery's API, you need to wrap it again inside a `$(...)`.

Try replacing :

```
temp_obj.append ...
```

with :

```
$(temp_obj).append
```

Actually, `.append` also works on a collection of nodes. If you can factor out your conditions :

```
var algSelect=grid.find('select[name=action_col1]');
var filtered = algSelect.filter(function(){  return some_cond_there; });

filtered.append('<option>'...'</option>');
```